# Why can't I drag anything onto 'activity_main.xml' in Android Studio?

Tags: android, ubuntu

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBD4xhH5vIE) on how to use Android Studio to create android apps. At time 17:13 in the video the user drags an object named "ImageButton" onto the picture (emulation) of a phone. I cannot do that, I see a sign like [image] instead.

How can I fix that in order to follow the tutorial?

Comment: Use the "Text" tab and create the xml yourself. You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: If you could provide a tutorial on THAT, or a link to the documentation to all I need to know to edit the xml mby myself, that would be pretty useful...

Comment: [Getting Started documentation](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/index.html) and [Building a UI Documentation](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) should both help. You have more control when you write the xml and it will help you better understand what is  happening in your code and how to place things.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at those...

Comment: Sure thing. Glancing over [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-xml-layouts--mobile-12749) it looks fairly easy to follow. Though, they use the deprecated `fill_parent` instead of `match_parent` for width/height. Just use the latter if you follow that one and it will do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see if you look at the xml text, the activity_main.xml now includes content_main.xml. So to edit the content of activity_main.xml you need to open content_main.xml and edit that with drag-and-drop or editing the raw file. This is just a new thing in the latest version of android studio. Everything on that main page used to be in activity_main instead of being split up into two xml files as it is now.